# Version Conflict on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document in ES. There is field A which currently has value {"Value1"}. Now two process starts in parallel, such that both tries to append some values to the field "A".
Lets say if both processes would not have been concurrent then the field "A" would have been like : {"Value1**Value2Value3**"} or {"Value1**Value3Value2**"}, i.e one request tries to append "Value2" and another request tries to append "Value3".But for concurrent requests, how to handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to read the [official blog on versioning support](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support) to understand how elasticsearch handles the concurrent updates to same doc.

Hint it uses the optimistic locking to improve the speed and you can use both internal or external versioning of your documents with below warning, but update API supports automatic retry in case of version conflict.

> update and update_by_query do not work with internal versioning.

Please refer [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) for further read.